# How to calculate the inside bounding box of an object with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to calculate the inside/ inner bounding box of a model imported into a three.js scene. As a simplified example, imagine a rectangular barn with walls of variable thickness, how could we calculate the inner dimensions of that barn?

I've tried creating a `Box3` and setting its dimensions directly from the barn object with Box3's `setFromObject` method. This works well for a typical bounding box, but I haven't been able to find any approaches to calculate the inside bounding box of an object.

[Example barn walls model with actual bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IskK.png)

[Top down view with desired inner bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8XMl.png)

Comment: I assume you're looking for optimal inner volume? i.e. bounding box must occupy the most possible space

Answer (score 2):

Use model slicing to reduce the problem from 3D to 2D.

**STEP 1** - slice the model with N of horizontal planes → get N shapes in 2D space, each with own Z height.

**STEP 2** - for each slice:

1. Find inner extreme lines (shown with red and green below)
2. Intersect extreme lines to build the inner rectangle at given Z height.

[image: finding best inner volume]

**STEP 3** - Having collection of rectangles, merge them into inner volume:

Inner volume will be a shape of the *smallest common* rectangle.
Check from what rectangles it results to know `min(Z)` and `max(Z)` of the given shape.

[image: finding best inner volume]

**OPTIMIZING for best volume**

Inner volume can be increased by excluding some slices, or adding new slices. For example we have inner diamond shape. Taking max(Z) and min(Z) will produce narrow column which is apparently not the best volume in this case.

Removing slices from top and bottom will improve results. Hope you get the idea, sorry my poor drawing skills!

[image: OPTIMIZING for best volume]